# When I run the app.js ,it shows the error "TypeError: knex.select is not a function"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, knex.js

I have this snippet code in *app.js* file,

```
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.render('login');
    var data = knex.select('*').from('RegisterData');
    res.send(data)
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: And how is `knex` defined?

Comment: Did you install knex in node?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen ,const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth-routes');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('./config/db');
const knex1 = require('./knexfile');
const knex = require('knex');        *this is how i defined all modules in my app.js file*

Comment: @AndiswamyRajagopal Please [edit] your _question_ to include details about how you included Knex.

Comment: @sk786 , I installed it globally

Answer (score 1):

In comments (you really should update your question to reflect these), you say you defined `knex` with:

```
const knex = require('knex');
```

You should have a look at the *Initializing the Library* paragraph in [Node.js installation section](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-node).

It's supposed to look like:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {...}
});
```

Which means `knex` should be the *result of a call to the function* exposed by `require`.

Answer (score 1):

Define knex based on the database you are using and assign it:

```
const knex = require("knex");

const database= knex({
  client: "mysql",
  connection: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "your_user_name_for_database",
    password: "password_if_any",
    database: "your_database"
  }
});
```

after that execute the query like this:

```
database.select("*").from("users");
```

Comment: Do you remember what version of knex this applied to?